# "Capital regimes" - explanation and types?

Tags: terminology

I have come across this term "capital regime" from the following quote:

> According to an overnight report from the FT which confirms what we
>   already disclosed previously, namely that JPMorgan pushed more than
>   $130bn of excess cash away from reserves in the process significantly
>   tightening overall liquidity in the interbank market, the bulk of this
>   money was allocated to long-dated bonds while cutting the amount of
>   loans it holds, in what the FT dubbed was a "major shift in how the
>   largest US bank by assets manages its enormous balance sheet."
>
> The moves saw the bank’s bond portfolio soar by 50%, and were prompted
>   by capital rules that treat loans as riskier than bonds. And since JPM
>   has been aggressively returning billions of dollars to shareholders in
>   dividends and share buybacks each year, JPMorgan has far less room
>   than most rivals to hold riskier assets, explaining its substantially
>   higher G-SIB surcharge.
>
> The dramatic change, which occurred gradually over the year, and which
>   may have catalyzed the spike in repo rates in September, was first
>   flagged by JPMorgan at an investor event back in February. After years
>   of industry-leading loan growth, “we have to recognize the reality of
>   the **capital regime** that we live in.” - Marianne Lake

Google did not turn up any definitions, which leads me to believe "capital regime" is not a wide-spread term. However, given the context, I was hoping I could still try to understand what she meant by the phrase.

I'm curious what "capital regime" are we in now, and why. Plus, for robustness, I'd like to know what other "capital regimes" are out there and what their characteristics are.

### Question

Even if it's not a standard phrase, let's humor her and ask the question: what types of capital regimes are theoretically possible, and which one are we in now (and why)?

Comment: I don't think it is an idiom or term. I think it is meant as the regime (the rules governing)... the capital

Comment: @StianYttervik Alright, that's probably a distinct possibility. In that case, what does "capital" mean here? Capital in general or are we supposed to infer a specific type of capital, like, "debt capital"?

Comment: In that specific context it would certainly be the capital held by banks (or that bank in particular): *"were prompted by capital rules that treat loans as riskier than bonds"* - so they offloaded loans and loaded up on bonds. which put a strain on the liquidity of interbank rates, if the source is to be believed. The comment is basically "well, the rules for capital changed, so the nature of allocating that capital changed with it":